# Modify HtmlWebpackPlugin's generated script URLs

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

When using HtmlWebpackPlugin to generate the dist/index.html file, we can use the inject option to automatically **create `<script>` tags for the javascript bundle files**:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: config.build.index,
    template: 'index.html',
    inject: true,
    // ...
})
```

And get an index.html file that looks similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Webpack App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For server side constraints, I need to **add a query string parameter in the generated script source**, to make it look like `<script src="index_bundle.js?my-parameter=my-value"></script>`. I've been looking at the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options), but I can't find the way to do it.

Is there any **option to modify the generated URLs**, by appending an string or replacing with a RegEx?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Based on [thedarkone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4942107/thedarkone)'s answer**, I provide the resolution for my question:

I added the query parameter in the **webpack configuration output parameter** (production build only in my case) and use HtmlWebpackPlugin with the default config:

```
const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    // ...
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js?my-parameter=my-value'),
    },
    // ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: config.build.index,
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true,
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Since I also need the query parameter in the style links, I also had to modify the **ExtractTextPlugin filename parameter** in the same way:

```
// ...
new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'bundle.[chunkhash].js'
    filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].css?my-parameter=my-value'),
})
// ...
```

Keep in mind that this approach will **append the query parameters to ALL of the injected scripts/styles**.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered doing that yourself by providing your own template to `HtmlWebpackPlugin`? It would look something like this:

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = () => ({
  entry: './burrito.js',
  output: {
    filename: './burrito_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'lunch.ejs',
      templateParameters: {
        query: '?foo=bar&bar=baz'
      },
      filename: 'lunch.html',
      inject: false,
    }),
  ],
});
```

In `lunch.ejs`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <% htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js.forEach(function(file) { %>
      <script src="<%= file %><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.templateParameters.query %>"></script>
    <% }) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

*`HtmlWebpackPlugin` will expose a global variable `htmlWebpackPlugin` for your template to read values from.
Cf. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates*

When you run Webpack, it will process your `lunch.ejs` template and produce `lunch.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="./burrito_bundle.js?foo=bar&bar=baz"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not using ejs and I don't want to include it in the solution just to generate the bundle

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, HtmlWebpackPlugin uses ejs by default so you wouldn't need to include any extra packages. But it is true that you would have to create an ejs template.

Comment: This solution does not work when you add hash to the filename. You don't know the name of the generated file

Answer (score 1):

```
output: {
    filename: `bundle.js?param=${Math.random()}`
}
```

This would add the query parameter to bundle.js

The file name would rename as bundle.js though

If you wanted to generate a new file every time, the below would be better suited

```
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.[chunkhash].js'
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the name of the generated files to bundle. Specially because I am using chunks to split the bundle in different scripts.